# message queue makefile error: undefined reference to `mq_open'

Tags: linux, makefile, message-queue

Even though I have linked `-lrt` in my Makefile, as you can see below, I am still getting `undefined reference to 'mq_open'`. Please help!

```
all:get1 iserv1
get: get1.c
    gcc -Wall -o get1 get1.c -lrt
iserv: iserv1.c
    gcc -Wall -o iserv1 iserv1.c -lrt
clean:
    rm -fr *~ get1 iserv1
```

Comment: Which version of glibc do you have ?

Answer (score 5):

Note -lrt should be at end not inbetween.

Answer (score 4):

Your makefile is wrong

```
all:get1 iserv1
get: get1.c
    gcc -Wall -o get1 get1.c -lrt
```

`all` has a prerequisite of `get1` and `iserv1`. But you created a `get` target and an `iserv` target. So e.g. get1 will be compiled with the default make rules, which does not include -lrt (this should show if you look at the gcc commands that actually are executed.)

Your makefile should like like this:

```
all:get1 iserv1
get1: get1.c
    gcc -Wall -o get1 get1.c -lrt
iserv1: iserv1.c
    gcc -Wall -o iserv1 iserv1.c -lrt
clean:
    rm -fr *~ get1 iserv1
```